# MySQLdb - Naming Tables using datetime module in Python

Tags: python, scrapy, mysql-python

I'm using the MySQLdb module in Python to create a table, but I've ran into some issues when trying to name it using the datetime module.

```
class DbPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    vendor = "vendorname"
    curDate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').replace("-", ".")
    tableName = vendor + ":" + curDate

    # connect to the database
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='', db='dbname', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    #create a new table
    sql = "CREATE TABLE %s (name CHAR(40))" %tableName
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

**This results in the following error:** 
" raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':2013.12.21 (name CHAR(40))' at line 1")

I'm pretty sure it might be something to do with character escaping or the way my sql query is defined, but plenty of Googling and REPL sessions later I've not managed to fix it.

Some code from REPL:

```
vendor = "vendorname"
curDate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').replace("-", ".")
tableName = vendor + ":" + curDate
sql = "CREATE TABLE %s (name CHAR(40))" %tableName
sql
'CREATE TABLE vendorname:2013.12.21 (name CHAR(40))'
```

Final little note, this works perfectly if you were to just assign %tableName a-z characters. Thanks for reading and apologies if this is something blindingly obvious I've missed!

Comment: Why `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').replace("-", ".")` not `time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')`?

Comment: I originally was using datetime.now().date() then converting that to a string, but a SO post used time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') and it seemed a nicer way of doing things.

Comment: You can alter the format string to give the format you need without any `replace`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: I've bookmarked that, thanks :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html):

> Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names.

Try:

```
curDate = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
tableName = "%s_%s" % (vendor, curDate)
```

For example, `"vendorname_20131221"`

Comment: I tried removing those characters completely, but still had the same problem. I'll give it another shot though!

Comment: Beautiful that did the trick! Thanks for that :D!. Looks like I need to read up some more on strings!